# PHP / MySQL Code Returning incorrect value

Tags: php, mysql

wondering if someone would spot what im getting wrong with my code below, it is returning the category_id and im wanting it to return the category any ideas anyone?

```
function fn_order_category_get_order_info($product_id) {
    $result = db_get_field("SELECT pc.category_id, cd.category FROM ?:products_categories pc LEFT JOIN ?:category_descriptions cd ON pc.category_id = cd.category_id WHERE product_id = $product_id;"); 
    return $result; 
}
```

Comment: Depends entirely on what `db_get_field()` does

Comment: Why are you SELECTing both fields when you only need one?  SELECT cd.category leave everything else the same?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

*Maybe* changing `SELECT pc.category_id, cd.category` to `SELECT cd.category, pc.category_id` will work.